# Clarification in TC Shell Script

Tags: unix, tcsh

I have a script in TC shell, for some reason its not working.

Can anyone point out the issue in the same

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
while true
do
    if ls /sample/test3 >& /dev/null  ; then /sample/app_code/run/initiateLoad.sh ; endif
    sleep 1800
done
```

The path /sample/test3 contains files so the if condition should have been successful and should have started the shell script, but its not happening.

Comment: You're testing the exit code of `ls`, not whether or not there are files in `/sample/test3`.

Comment: testing exit code of `ls` is appropriate, as it returns 1 if no files match, but [t]csh don't evaluate an embedded cmd the way ksh/bash/sh do.  Maybe `if (\`ls /s/test3\` >&/dev/null ) ; then .... ` will work. Else find the correct form for `test` in csh. (All of my csh code is on a 3 1/2" floppy, and the usually helpful http://www.grymoire.com/Unix` isn't helping yeilding the advice we need.) Of course, the advise is "Stop using [t]csh for scripting!", but sometimes thats easier said than done. Good luck.